# How can I get a CSL file to number the bibliography consecutively?

Tags: latex, bibliography, citations, csl

I'm using the csl file below (from Zotero), but there's a problem. I have text like:

```
This is citation one by Jones [1]. This is citation two by Bell [2]. ...This is citation nine by Smith [9].
```

In the references, it is listed like:

```
2. Bell, ...
1. Jones, ...
9. Smith, ...
```

What I want is:

```
This is citation one by Jones [2]. This is citation two by Bell [1]. ...This is citation nine by Smith [3].

1. Bell, ...
2. Jones, ...
3. Smith, ...
```

How do I adjust the csl file to get what I want? It's supposed to be SIGCHI Proceedings, but it doesn't match the style in a PDF supplied by the conference.

The csl file is located here:

http://www.zotero.org/styles/acm-sigchi-proceedings

Comment: Is this with Zotero? Can you provide a link to the PDF that shows the required style? The current CSL style links to the 2009 SIGCHI website, which might have outdated instructions.

Comment: http://www.sigchi.org/publications/chipubform/sigchi-papers-latex-template/at_download/file

Comment: The bibliography is bibtex. I'm using Pandoc to render the PDF, with this CSL file in the Pandoc command.

Comment: In that case you're probably best off reporting this as an issue in the citeproc-hs issue tracker (citeproc-hs is the CSL processor integrated into pandoc). See http://code.google.com/p/citeproc-hs/issues/list . Don't forget to include a link to this page.

Comment: Is there any work-around that I can use to get the bibliography to number properly and have that proper numbering be reflected in the citations in the paper? Maybe there are some changes that can be done in the csl file?

Comment: See my amended answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not explicitly mentioned in the CSL specification, the citation-numbers of bibliographic entries should always be in order, even when the entries are alphabetically sorted by author (as is the case for the SIGCHI CSL style), so this probably should be fixed in the CSL processor.

[edit: this bug has been reported and has been fixed: https://code.google.com/p/citeproc-hs/issues/detail?id=83&can=1 ]

Comment: Thanks, Rintze, but the problem remains despite changing the CSL. I've contacted the library author, who seems to have identified the problem and is working on fixing it.